# How to display tool tips of a description when the mouse hovers over a column in .NET with WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013, hover, mouse

I am new to .NET and WFP.
Using Visual Studio 2013, .NET framework 4.5 with WPF. Showing a list of items in a table, columns: id (auto-increment), name, value, image, date-modified. I want to display the description of the list-item when the mouse is hovering the name column. The name column MAX LENGTH is 100 characters and the description is 2048 characters (2KB).

I tried several ways, but it doesn't work, most likely I am doing something wrong.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi Binyamin , could you please provide the sample code so we can process the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a menu-option CONFIGURATION and it contains a table with the following columns (fields): id, name, value, description, tools, refers-to, last-updater, last-updated. The description column can contain a lot of text and I wanted to display the entire text in a tool tip when I hover over description column with the mouse.
Here is the code how I did it:

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="47*"  MinWidth="100" Header="{DynamicResource Configuration_DataGridHeader_Description}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock  Style="{DynamicResource WrappedTrimedTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Description}">
                            <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip >
                                    <TextBlock Width="600" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```